# CentOS 7 statically configured network adapter keeps getting DHCP address

Tags: linux, networking, centos, interface

This is driving me nuts.  I have a CentOS 7 system.  It is acting as DHCP for the network it is attached to, is running Cobbler and PXE, but it is not the gateway.  It is the primary file server for my network.

I have an on-board network adapter configured to be static that is also the adapter that DHCP is being handed out on:

```
# Generated by dracut initrd
NAME="enp5s0f0"
DEVICE="enp5s0f0"
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
#NETBOOT=yes
UUID="82b4ef5d-6c06-43f1-a0fe-7b5fcdd1fc4f"
#IPV6INIT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=10.101.24.21
NETMASK=255.255.252.0
TYPE=Ethernet
GATEWAY=10.101.24.1
```

This adapter, about once a week, decides it wants to override the statically configured IP, and get a DHCP address.  Not after booting up.  Just sitting there.  Operating normally.  At this point, I have to physically walk to the terminal or log in with IPMI to type:

```
systemctl restart network
```

And that brings it right back to the static address.  Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: I know it's dracut but can't tell you exactly whats happening

Comment: FWIW, for the static IPs on my RHEL7 systems, I use `BOOTPROTO=none`.

Answer (score 4):

The `BOOTPROTO` parameter only accepts the following values:

```
 BOOTPROTO=protocol    ## where protocol is one of the following:

    none — No boot-time protocol should be used.
    bootp — The BOOTP protocol should be used.
    dhcp — The DHCP protocol should be used.
```

According to the RHEL Network documentation. Dracut is probably running past the network init script using it's ifcfg module and defaulting it to `dhcp` since it doesn't know what `static` means. You might also try omitting the `ifcfg` module in dracut to see if that does what you expect, as well.

Comment: Ok, that sounds plausible.  I tried this.  I'll post back here in a week or so if it hasn't done it again and mark this as the answer!

Comment: This didn't work either :/  I suspect that it's some kind of Cobbler or other software related thing at this point.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that my centos had been migrated twice as a virtual host.
After that my server started deciding that it would use a dhcp-address instead of the statically assigned one.

Finally I removed the "UUID" row entirely and that seems to have fixed it for me.
So maybe in your case your network card has gotten a new UUID and that is the issue?

These are just guesses from my end though.
Best Regards
Charlie

Comment: I had ro remove the mac address line as well. After that, the system assigned the static IP.